# How to express "Please don't hold or keep the milk or water in your mouth, swallow it"?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions, sentence-usage

Sometimes, my little child takes a sip of water or milk & then he keeps or holds the sip in his mouth without swallowing it.

Is it idiomatic to say "**Please don't hold or keep the milk or water in your mouth, swallow it**"?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

(Of course, you would most likely choose one possibility and only say that.)

"Please don't **keep** the **water** in your mouth, swallow it."

"Please don't **hold** the **water** in your mouth, swallow it."